# AWS cognito identity pool ABAC how to map custom multi-valued attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Example open id token from the identity provider (Cognito user pool in this example):

```
{
  "cognito:groups": [
    "testers",
    "admins",
  ],
  "email_verified": false,
  ...
}
```

I want to use ABAC, like the example given here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-attributes-for-access-control-policy-example.html

So that I can add policy statements to the role associated with the Cognito identity pool with conditions, example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "rds-db:connect",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds-db:eu-west-1:123456789012:dbuser:cluster-teapot/db-user",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalTag/groups": "admins"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It works like a charm if you use single valued custom claims, like the "email_verified" above, but if I try to map array-valued claims like "cognito:groups"

```
aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity...
```

fails with: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.

[image: Configuring custom attributes in identity pool]

This is not a problem with trust since its tried and tested with single-valued claims, so I am wondering if someone knows if the syntax is wrong, or if this is a missing feature?

Comment: I also have this issue, did you find a solution for it?

Comment: I talked to AWS, this is not currently supported. I ended up flattening an array claim as a workaround

Comment: Did write a lambda to take the groups and flatten them in a new claim?

Comment: Yes, I think I used the pre-token generation hook in Cognito if I remember it correctly

Comment: Same problem, it's crazy we need this kind of workaround, they don't even mention this in their documentation

Comment: It seems like I have found a workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971405/cognito-identity-pools-attribute-based-access-control-with-dynamic-attribute/71016107#71016107